# How Do I Plot Color Distribution of HSV Image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, visualization

I have a dataset of images representing human skin. How do I plot the skin color distribution in HSV color space and YCBCR color space. However, I'd like ignore the "value" or "brightness" in both color spaces and analyze rest of the layers.

**edit**

The below is the code, I found to plot the distribution for ycbcr but don't understand what it means. Can anyone explain it please?

```
chroma = zeros(256);
cb = imycc(:,:,2);
cb = reshape(cb, 1, numel(cb));
cb = round(cb);

cr = imycc(:,:,3);
cr = reshape(cr, 1, numel(cr));
cr = round(cr);

for i = 1:length(cb)
   chroma(cb(i), cr(i)) = chroma(cb(i), cr(i)) + 1;
end
surf(chroma)
```

Comment: why don't you just extract Ihsv(:,:,1) or Ihsv(:,:,2) for further processing

Comment: yes, after extracting h and s layers as you mentioned.. how do I plot the distribution

Comment: The code is pretty clear, it just count the number of (cb(i),cr(i)) combinations under the assumption of cb, and cr value all locates within the range of 1-256 (or 0-255 in your case)

Comment: Okay!, when in the case of normalized values, how should I do it?

Comment: chroma(round(cb(i)*256), round(cr(i)*256)) = chroma(round(cb(i)*256), round(cr(i)*256)) + 1;

Comment: @0cool, Could you review my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [File Exchange Submission - RGB/HSV Distribution](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/49002) on  visualization of RGB/HSV distribution in a given image:

```
hsv_distribution(inputImage, 5)
```

It should do what you're after as the result is like:

[image]